# About uncertainty/error of speed of light?

Tags: physical-constants

Physicists defined the speed of light in vacuum as:
$$c=2.997\,924\,58\cdot 10^{8}\,{m}/{s}.$$

So the significant figures of it is infinite?

And a constant is said to be defined means it comes from rigorous math something?

Comment: No. It is used in essence to define the meter.

Comment: Quite clever that the most accurate way of measuring the length of something is now timing how quickly the fastest thing in the universe travels along it !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first question, yes, the value given for the speed of light has infinite precision and infinite significant figures. The use of the value of $c$ in a calculation does not add any error to the result.

For your second question, the speed of light being "defined" to a certain value is more like a dictionary definition. "When I say the word X, I actually mean this." It's not so different from defining "dozen" to mean 12 or "pair" to mean 2. Here's how a few physics definitions fit together:

- **speed of light**: *[noun]* a speed whose numerical value is exactly $299\,792\, 458$ meters per second.
- **second**: *[noun]* an amount of time during which exactly $9\,192\,631\,770$ wavelengths of light are emitted from a cesium-133 atom as it transitions between two hyperfine levels of its ground state.
- **meter**: *[noun]* the distance traveled by an object traveling at the speed of light in exactly $1/299\,792\, 458$ of a second.

Notice that the definition of the meter use the value of the speed of light. This means that in order to define what we mean by the word "meter," we need to define what we mean by "speed of light" and "second" first. The numbers were picked so that the resulting second and meter would be virtually indistinguishable from the those currently in use by scientists.

Answer (score 2):

On first meeting the definition of the metre as a base SI unit one may be puzzled and consider it bizarre and yet there is method in the madness.

The current definition of metre has come about because a frequency can be measured more accurately and with much greater precision than a wavelength.

The speed of light is a fundamental constant and in the past has been the subject of intense research in trying to determine an accurate value in terms of wavelength (SI base unit - metre) and the frequency (directly related to SI base unit - second).

The limiting factor in terms of accuracy in the measurement of the speed of light was found to be the measurement of length when it was based on the measuring wavelengths related to the wavelength of light from a Krypton-86 source.

So in $1983$ it was decided to choose the then best currently available value for the speed of light $(2.997\,924\,58\times 10^{8}\;\rm m \, s^{-1})$ to be the defined (**exact**) value of the speed of light and then use it to define the metre in terms of that exact speed of light and a time which could be found from measurements of frequency.
The change in definition did not mean that distance measuring instruments had to be recalibrated rather it meant that in future distances could be measured more accurately.
The defined value of the speed of light had no mathematical basis rather it was based on experimental values.

The importance of work in the field of precise frequency measurement was recognised by the award of a Nobel Prize in Physics in 2005 to Roy Glauber, John Hall and Theodor Hänsch and it might be of interest to read the [press release](https://www.nobelprize.org/nobel_prizes/physics/laureates/2005/popular-physicsprize2005.pdf) and more detail given in [Theodor Hänsch's Nobel Lecture](https://d22izw7byeupn1.cloudfront.net/files/RevModPhys.78.1297.pdf).

The Wikipedia article [Metre](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metre) is informative as is the Evenson and Petrsen’s much older article [Laser Frequency Measurements, the Speed of Light, and the Meter](http://tf.nist.gov/general/pdf/307.pdf) which gives a pre-1983 perspective of metrology and correctly postulated what did happen to the definition of the metre in the last section entitled *6.6. Possible New Standard of Length*.

Answer (score 1):

The speed of light is now a defined value as per above.
Given the value of the second defined as the duration of 9 192 631 770 periods of the radiation corresponding to the transition between the two hyperfine levels of the ground state of the cesium 133 atom, one obtains the value of the standard meter.

With these choices of numerical values, the length the standard meter is almost exactly the usual length of the "old, everyday" meter (meant to be  $10^{-7}$ of the length of the meridian through Paris from North Pole to the equator) and the standard second is almost exactly the duration of "old, everyday" second.

Comment: In other words, the speed of light in m/s is fixed. The length of a second is fixed (in a different way) so if we measure a better value of the speed of light we change the length of the meter

Comment: "Given the value of the second defined as the... one obtains the value of the standard meter". Did you mean second?

Comment: @MartinBeckett Given the way the metre is currently defined there is no way to "measure a better value for the speed of light".

Comment: @Farcher philosophically no, practically yes. If a new method adds a decimal place it changes the defn of the meter - although of course the headline speed of light doesn't change